# Date time conversion issue in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
declare @a datetime = '20/05/2019 9:22:07'
```

I want output as:

```
2019-05-20 9:22:07
```

I tried :

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@a,10),103),101);

SELECT convert(varchar, convert(date, @a, 105), 101)
```

But it gives me an error:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

How to convert this type of data?

I want to get the standard date time conversion which will work in all languages

Comment: Don't use localized strings in the first place. There's no Month 20 in the US for example. Use an unambiguous format, like `YYYYMMDD` for dates or the ISO8601 format for data and time values.

Comment: `I want output as:` I suspect there's some confusion here. Dates have no format, they are binary values, like ints. No matter what string you use to create a date value, the result is exactly the same. Formats apply only when that date gets converted to a string for display on a client, eg an application or SSMS. Windows applications use the *user's locale settings* to display dates, unless that's overriden incode

Comment: If you want it to be datetime in the first place, and also work regardless of date settings and locale, and version of Sql Server then use a format like 'yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss'. Note that there is no separators between yyyy MM and dd: declare @a datetime; set datetime = '20190520 09:22:07'; (older versions do not support assignment on the same line as declaration).

Comment: Eg `declare @a datetime='2019-05-20T09:22:07'`

Answer (score 2):

Your conversion problem is occurring here:

```
declare @a datetime = '20/05/2019 9:22:07';
```

I think you intend this as a string:

```
declare @a varchar(255) = '20/05/2019 9:22:07';
```

To get the time with only one digit for the hour, you can use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@a, 10), 103), 120) + ' ' + TRIM(RIGHT(@a, 8))
```

More commonly, you would use:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, @a, 103), 120)
```

This produces:

```
2019-05-20 09:22:07
```

Comment: Or use `declare @a datetime='2019-05-20 09:22:07'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos . . . It is not reasonable to convert a date/time value to a date/time value, so I'm pretty sure the OP wants to start with a string.

Comment: The question shows a *lot* of confusion, so I suspect the OP confused dates, strings and (non-existent) date formats. `I want output as:` probably means the OP thinks dates values have a specific format

Comment: Is it possible to have a variable as datetime rather than varchar

Comment: @RedDevil you already have a `datetime` variable. You just tried to assign a localized string to it. `declare @a datetime='2019-05-20 09:22:07'` would work just fine

Comment: Problem here is I am working on spanish and english version of SQl, and in spanish they follow dmy format and in english it is mdy. So if i fix dateformat issue in english it doesnot work in spanish

Comment: @GordonLinoff Variable @a is datetime not varchar and if I run the query without conversion in Spanish database it works but in english it gives an error

Comment: @RedDevil that's why you *shouldn't* use localized formats. `declare @a datetime = '2019-05-20T09:22:07'` works just fine no matter where you work. So does `declare @a datetime = '20190520'` `I don't work in the US either

Comment: @RedDevil the behavior of date literals [is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetime). The ISO8601 and unseparated formats work in any language

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you mean to say if my date is coming from the front end I should convert it in standard format there itself?

Comment: @RedDevil that's a different question and no - the date should come as a date-typed parameter in a parameterized query. Dates in OLEDB, ADO.NET or ODBC have no format either. Parameters in a parameterized query are passed as strongly-typed values separately from the query itself, so no conversion issues occur when you send a date or double as a parameter